# Why is "main" not a function in my OpenWhisk action?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, serverless, openwhisk

I'm trying to upload a zipped action to IBM's OpenWhisk.

> "Initialization has failed due to: Action entrypoint 'main' is not a
>   function."

But I'm quite sure that "main" is a function, and I've tried defining it in multiple ways. As tutorials suggest, I've tried both:

```
function processComment(params) {
    // some code
    return {success:1};
}
exports.main = processComment;
```

and

```
function main(params) {
    // some code
    return {success:1};
}
```

This code is all contained in a file is called index.js, and I've tried it with and without the following line in my package.json:

```
"main": "index.js",
```

I even looked up the relevant code in OpenWhisk, and it seems to be a straightforward type check to see if main is a function:

```
if (typeof thisRunner.userScriptMain !== 'function') {
    throw "Action entrypoint '" + message.main + "' is not a function.";
}
```

So I assume it's just not finding "main" in the right place... But I'm really lost. Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a zip file? If not you’ve hit a limitation of the current node.js runtime as explained in this issue https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-runtime-nodejs/issues/14 which requires a zipped source file instead.

If you are using a zip, did you place the package.json and index.js filed at the root path?

As a zip file:

index.js:

```
function processComment(params) {
    // some code
    return {success:1};
}
exports.main = processComment;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-action",
  "main": "index.js"
}
```

And using the CLI:

```
$ zip s.zip index.js package.json
$ wsk action create s s.zip --kind nodejs:6
$ wsk action invoke s -r
{
    "success": 1
}
```

Comment: I didn't use the "zip" command, because I'm in windows -- I used 7zip's explorer context menu option, but I can confirm that index.js and package.json are both at the root.

So... yeah, this is a mystery?

Comment: One note: I made the action in the IBM web interface, and then updated it with a zip file once I realized that I needed that to do that to get a package.json into the mix.

Comment: You updated the action with the zip file using the web interface or the cli?

Comment: Can you upload your sample zip file somewhere? I'm happy to test it out and check the commands are working.